Cannot configure ScrollView paging behaviour to have correct both paging size and snapping animation velocity
iOS version: 17.0
My goal is to implement a vertical paging behaviour in ScrollView that satisfies these conditions:

vertical size of every page should be vertical screen size - size of the tab bar
It should have a quick snapping animation for every page, it cannot skip any pages
the tab bar doesn't have to be transparent, I don't care about the visibility of the content behind the tab bar

This is an illustration of what I want to achieve:

I implemented 2 versions of the code, but non of them can satisfy all the conditions:
1 version, using .paging behaviour:
struct CardView: View {
    
    var color: Color
    
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .fill(color)
    }
    
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    let randomColors: [Color] = [
        .red,
        .green,
        .blue,
        .yellow,
        .orange
        ]
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(randomColors, id: \.self) { color in
                        CardView(color: color)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.vertical)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .top)
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
            .scrollIndicators(.never)
            .tabItem {
                Label("ScrollView", systemImage: "1.circle")
            }
        }
    }
}

How it works:

You can see here that scrolling offset is not correct, it scrolls more points than needed.
Also I didn't find any way to explicitly configure the size of scrollable page.
2 version, using .viewAligned:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let randomColors: [Color] = [
        .red,
        .green,
        .blue,
        .yellow,
        .orange
        ]
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0) {
                    ForEach(randomColors, id: \.self) { color in
                        CardView(color: color)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                            .containerRelativeFrame(.vertical)
                            .scrollTargetLayout()

                    }
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .top)
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            .scrollIndicators(.never)
            .tabItem {
                Label("ScrollView", systemImage: "1.circle")
            }
        }
    }
}

How it works:
Have to provide s link, as stackoverflow doesn't let me to upload gif for some reason, though it is of correct size and resolution
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PavelKatunin/public_test_files/refs/heads/main/ezgif-3-28a1575f7b.gif
You can see that the animation is too slow, and also it can skip some of the pages.
I tried many different approaches, tried to use content insets and margins, and also tried to implement some UIKit logic of UIScrollView. It never worked.
Is there a reliable way to configure pagination offsets and snapping animation velocity?

This answer might help: iOS 17 SwiftUI: Color Views in ScrollView Using containerRelativeFrame Overlap When Scrolling
